BSOD - CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT error
When I'm away from computer or if I leave it on overnight, I see a BSOD (CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT) when I come back. I thought it was related to chrome or ublock origin chrome extension. But I decided to use Opera instead of chrome and yet there was BSOD while I was away.
Bluescreen minidump Viewer shows its caused by ntoskrnl.exe or PSHED in mini dumps.


Update: I decided to test the processor using Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool 64 bit and found that it crashes and BSOD with the error WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR.
Memory was tested using Windows Memory Diagnostic and no issue was found. Also HDD looks good under Crystal Disk Info.
After digging into it I figured out OverClocking was the reason. I had set the OC voltage to Auto in BIOS a few days earlier and since then the issue started.
Disabling the OverClocking and reverting to default fixed the issue.
